# Connect to racadm via SSH, console is blank and non-responsive

Tags: linux, remote-access, firefox, drac

I have DRAC5 installed on a PowerEdge server running CentOS.  I'm able to SSH into the DRAC and issue racadm commands.

When I issue

```
connect com2
```

I briefly see a prompt:

[image]

A second later the screen goes blank and my quit key sequence does not work (neither does anything else - screen is unresponsive to all keys).

[image]

After closing out of the terminal and logging back into racadm for a second try with `connect com2`, it shows:

```
connect: com2 port is currently in use
```

After resetting racadm I can again try to connect com2, but get the same thing as above (blank/unresponsive screen).

Here is my config:

```
# racadm getconfig -g cfgSerial
cfgSerialBaudRate=57600
cfgSerialConsoleEnable=1
cfgSerialConsoleQuitKey=^q
cfgSerialConsoleIdleTimeout=300
cfgSerialConsoleNoAuth=0
cfgSerialConsoleCommand=
cfgSerialHistorySize=8192
cfgSerialCom2RedirEnable=1
cfgSerialTelnetEnable=0
cfgSerialSshEnable=1
```

I'd like to be able to view the console to remotely enter a password on an encrypted system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting to get this to work from Linux Mint with Firefox.  I tried again from a Windows 7 machine and IE, and was eventually able to get the console to display where I could see and enter commands.